What is meant by optical density?
I’m trying to research about optical density for a school task, but the definitions online are confusing me.
From what I’ve gotten, optical density is:

how much the intensity of light is increased or decreased upon entering some medium
how much a medium speeds or slows down the speed of the light

Are these like separate definitions for different fields? I was thinking the first was a definition for optometry and the second was the definition we use in physics?

Take a look at the RP Photonics Encyclopedia article on Optical Density
